# BorderLayout - child component remains visible after adding another component

Tags: java, swing, jframe, layout-manager, border-layout

I try to do the following thing:

1. Add a component to a `JFrame` with a `BorderLayout`
2. Add another component to the `JFrame`

I would expect the new component to 'overwrite' the old component, since I'm using a `BorderLayout`. This works if I overwrite the old component before I call `pack()`. Now if I add the 2nd component *after* I call `pack()`, both components remain visible. Example:

```
public class Test extends JFrame{
    public Test(){
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(new JLabel("Quite a long text"));
        setVisible(true);
        pack();
        add(new JLabel("Another text"));
    }
}
```

Result: [image: Calling pack() before adding the component]

```
public class Test extends JFrame{
    public Test(){
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(new JLabel("Quite a long text"));
        setVisible(true);
        add(new JLabel("Another text"));
        pack();
    }
}
```

Result: [image: Calling pack() after adding the component]

I tried adding `validate();` and `repaint();`, but that wouldn't help. What's going wrong here?

Comment: You can try `getComponents()[0] = new JLabel("Another Text");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling things that affect the UI after setViisble() is called -- a Swing no-no.  Put things that affect the UI into an invokeLater call; look it up.

While you're at it, I think you're still supposed to get the content pane from the frame for adding components...  And I don't think creating things in the constructor is a good idea.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class SwingTest extends JFrame
{
    public void createUI()
    {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
                new Runnable()
                {
                    public void run()
                    {
                        getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                        getContentPane().add(new JLabel("Quite a long text"), BorderLayout.CENTER);
                        getContentPane().add(new JLabel("Another text"), BorderLayout.CENTER);
                        pack();
                        setVisible(true);
                    }
                }
                );
    }

    public static void main(String ... args) 
    { 
        SwingTest st = new SwingTest();
        st.createUI();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure for `JFrame`s, `frame.getContentPane().add` is equivilent to `frame.add()`

Comment: Yes, as it turns out, you can remove getContentPane() from the above.  And there's no need to set borderLayout on the content pane, that's its default...

Comment: Well, back when I was in high school, we used null layout for everything lol. It's crippled me forever since.

Comment: @rcook Thanks for the feedback. Doing all the stuff in the constructor is just for the sake of the example :) 
However, in my case I _need_ to add things after setVisible(). The only way I got it working for now, is by manually removing the CENTER component from the layout, before adding the new component:

BorderLayout l = new BorderLayout();
... getContentPane().remove(l.getLayoutComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER));